# Why does my input not get validated when I'm not utilizing razor Html helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, xss

Say I have a simple web form that does not utilize razor html helpers/a model.

```
<form id="survey-form" action="@Url.Action("Submit", "Questionnaire")" method="post">
   <textarea name="1" form="survey-form">
</form>
```

The above form gets submitted using

```
$("#survey-form").submit();
```

Which posts to the following test method on a controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(true)]
public ActionResult Submit()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    return View();
}
```

`<script>alert("xss!")</script>` into my text input does not get validated by the controller. Where I would normally expect the `"A potentially dangerous Request.Form was detected from the client ..."` exception to be thrown.

The Method does not return any exceptions or messages and is allowed to run.

The MSDN documentation says

> The HttpRequest class uses input validation flags to track whether to perform validation on the request collections accessed through the **Cookies, Form, and QueryString properties**.

Since I am posting and processing a posted form with potentially dangerous values I would expect my input to be validated.

Is it possible for me to still utilize a simple MVC helper like the ValidateInput attribute, to validate user input without using the ASP.NET MVC conventions? (eg. creating a form using razor html helpers and a model etc.)

Edit: 
As there seems to be some confusion of the values actually reaching my Action on the Controller, here is a screenshot showcasing that the values do reach the function. 
[image]

Comment: You input does not have a name attribute, therefore its value is not posted.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The example I posted is a very shortened version for brevity sake. Thank you for the suggestion. In my actual project the values are passed and I am able to find them in my locals window when reading the properties into a NameValueCollection. No validation however.

Comment: Then show your real code!

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? @StephenMuecke I've slightly updated the post to better reflect the real situation. For brevity I do not think it's necessary to include all the fields in the form as they are all simple text input fields. Also attached a screenshot showing the values being posted to the controller.

Comment: There is no such thing as `<input type="textarea"`. Give your input a proper name (for testing say `name="xx"` and add a parameter in your method `string `xx`) and you will receive the error message.

Comment: I had made a mistake while updating the question and I've updated it to properly reflect that. It is <textarea ... >. This was not the problem however. It was indeed the fact that my action had no arguments. As Majdi Saibi suggested in his answer this seems to have solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Using `FormCollection` is awful practice - use a model and bind to it. The issue is that the error is only throw when you attempt to access a value (and it would have been throw if you had added `var value = Request.Form["1"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should include `FormCollection` as an argument for the `Submit` ActionResult.

Comment: Hi Majdi. I did as you suggested, however the input is still not validated I'm afraid.

Comment: The data is not posted to the controller because the Foo ActionResult does not have any arguments, also the input fields does not have a name attribute.

Comment: I've tested the updated suggestions. I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2.  but have tried using both requestValidationMode 4.0 and 4.5 to no avail. Values are still not validated, but are passed to the controller. (Also see the screenshot I attached to the question)

Comment: So, I think you should post the data as the ActionResult arguments

Comment: Majdi you are fantastic. I changed the controller action to include a FormCollection argument. The values are returned from it and my message is being being validated! I get the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from client.." when entering javascript into my inputs. You should update this to be an answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)